# Pytube direct video downloading without any folder

Tags: python, streamlit, pytube

I finished a streamlit app that basically downloads video and audio using pytube, and currently, I want to deploy it so that me and the others can use it on their phones, comps, and so on. However, when I deploy it and use it from another device, even though the model itself works, the file is not downloaded. Therefore I want to make it to be downloaded directly from chrome. (like the way that pictures and others are downloaded from chrome). Is there any particular method or trick for that? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [mre] read this

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide code of your app. For specify a download directory in pytube you need to write

```
directory = '/home/user/Documents'
file.download(directory)
```